# Type for Object.keys(someEnum) in typescript

Tags: typescript

In my problem, I am extracting keys of an enum using `Object.keys` as follows:

```js
const enum Foo {
    FOO = 'foo',
    BAR = 'bar'
}

const keys = Object.keys(Foo)
```

When I then try to use the same keys to point at values from `Foo` enum, I am getting the following error:

```js
Foo[keys[0]] // Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'typeof Foo'.
```

What kind of type should I cast `keys` to in order for the above to work?

Comment: Your example code gives an error unrelated to your question; there is no object named `Foo` at runtime. Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/NdoQQw) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a playground example which casts the Object.keys to the value of the enum keys, and allows indexing access.

If you see the logs you'll see it logs foo and bar.

```
enum Foo {
    FOO = 'foo',
    BAR = 'bar'
}

const keys = Object.keys(Foo) as (keyof typeof Foo)[]

keys.forEach((a) => {
    console.log(a)
})
```

[image]
[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAYg9nKBvAUFdsDymoF4oDkAZggQDRoYBCAggEp6EBGAhgE4EoC+KKAxnBABnAC5QA1sACeQxpiYArYHxEA6STIAU8OAEooLWZo1wiUEVIAOwU7AS6A2gF1eGoapJsAoiz4ALTWNpfVwAPmRKdAFhOAAbYFVYuABzTQJQSAlpAC5yLKldSKhooTiEpNT08GgANxZYsGA8nQcNJ0KuXSA)

Answer (score 2):

`const enum` is not compiled to an object. in fact , if you don't use `Foo.BAR` it is getting erased. Please see TS playground

```js
const enum Foo {
    FOO = 'foo',
    BAR = 'bar'
}
```

compiles to `"use strict"`, in other words to empty file.

[image]

If you want it to be compiled, please use `dot` notation:

```js
const enum Foo {
    FOO = 'foo',
    BAR = 'bar'
}

Foo.BAR
```

compiles to:

```js
"use strict";
"bar" /* BAR */;
```

[image]

However, if you even get rid of `const`, you will not get rid of error, because `enums` are staticaly known values. You are not allowed to use computed keys as a getter.

Hence, you are allowed to use either `Foo.BAR` or `Foo['BAR']`

Comment: [Please replace/supplement images of code/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)